# os.walk not returning all directories after switching python versions

Tags: python

After switching to 64-bit python from 32-bit I'm experiencing a strange error in os.walk or os.listdir functions. They're not returning all directories and their files, for example, I've got two folders such as:

```
folder_1 = C:\\vhosts\\VIDEO_TWO_CLONE\\28\\0
folder_2 = C:\\vhosts\\VIDEO_TWO_CLONE\\28\\1
```

both folders contain two sub-folders named "0", and "1"

I am not getting all folders with the first directory (e.g. folder_1):

```
for root, directories, files in os.walk(folder_1):
    print directories
    #got only ['0'] but missing ['1']
```

with folder_2 it works.

Comment: Sound like problem with permission to read a folder. Do you have right privilege to read/write that "1" folder ?

Comment: nope its fully readable and writable all sub-folders were generated dynamically...don't understand why my system can't detect its trace

Comment: Have you tried running it recursively as in:
`for root, directories, files in os.walk(folder_1):
    for directory in directories:
         print directory`
I know the wrapping is screwed..

Comment: It now seems to be working after deleting old pyc files that my system used for 32-bit of python. Now, I am using 64-bit.